# How to add properties inside an object by calling function in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Given below is an object stored in variable nestedObject. Inside this object,
you can see a property with keyname countries with 1 object value (switzerland).
I want to create a function with 4 arguments: object,countryName, capital, population which
adds a new key-value pair inside countries object and return the value of a newly inserted key.
The key being countryName and value, an object with properties as shown in the example.

**I want to Create a new function to add country with the name, capital, and population as parameters
---Then Call the function with given parameter values
---Return the result in the output variable**

Given below is the format of the object which will be passed as the argument.

````
  speakers: [{ name: "Elie" }, { name: "Tim" }, { name: "Matt" }],
  data: {
    continents: {
      europe: {
        countries: {
          switzerland: {
            capital: "Bern",
            population: 38000000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    languages: {
      spanish: {
        hello: "Hola"
      },
      french: {
        hello: "Bonjour"
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign` for this purpose ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)).

Your question can be done using `assign` as

```
var countryName={capital:capital,population:population};
const ans=Object.assign(object.data.continents.europe.countries,countryName);
```